# Trying to monitor filemaker

Tags: monitoring, filemaker, health-monitoring

So I am trying to monitor whether my filemaker infinite-loop script is running. What would be the best way?

I noticed filemaker does not spawn a new process when a background script runs so checking processes or threads probably is out of the question.

My current solution involves checking the UI for the "Script paused" sub-window in the Filemaker client  which is kind of flaky. Are there any better ways to check. Filemaker does not seem to have any support for such checks.

Filemaker version: 14.0 Pro

EDIT: Maybe, I should have been more clear. I am trying to monitor this via monitoring tools such as, zabbix. So I have an external (powershell) script that checks filemaker.

Comment: More details would probably help. Is this a FileMaker script, a shell script, a plugin script? "Background script" isn't a standard term in the FileMaker community. I'm assuming you mean a shell script of some sort that's being executed from a FileMaker script, but would need to be sure before offering any advice.

Comment: basically a normal filemaker script that runs infinitely. should I remove the wording altogether?

Comment: I would edit the question to reflect that it's an infinite-loop FileMaker script, but that fact also leads me to ask why you're using an infinite-loop script. :) Depending on the version of FileMaker you're using, there are other tools available that can accomplish what infinite-loop scripts used to be required for.

Comment: So the main reason is that, we have to sync database entries with a postgres database. Hence the script.

Comment: Which version of FileMaker are you working with? Is the database hosted with FileMaker Server?

Comment: Postgres Database is on a remote server (connect via ODBC), we are using "Actual" postgres adapter for this. The filemaker server is hosted along with the client.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91034/discussion-between-mirage-and-chuck).

Comment: Try emailing me at chivalry@mac.com. I think we would need to back up a step to look at the larger picture before attempting a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on continuing to use an infinitely looping script, here's how I would indicate that the script is running in FileMaker 13+:

- Each time the loop executes, update a global variable to the current timestamp (`Set Variable [ $$_LAST_LOOP_EXECUTED ; Get ( CurrentTimestamp ) ]`).
- Add some text to the layout. The text is what is going to show when the script's loop executed recently.
- Edit the "Hide object when" calculation (found on the "Data" tab of the Info panel) to read something like this: `Get ( CurrentTimestamp ) - $$_LAST_LOOP_EXECUTED > 60`. This assumes that if the global variable hasn't been updated during the past minute, the script is *not* executing.

If you're not using at least FileMaker 13, getting this done will a bit more complicated, but is possible with conditional formatting.

All the above is a workaround to the fact that once you start the script, since it's designed to always run, you might halt it by clicking the "Cancel" button while it's paused, which means the script can't perform any cleanup such as clearing a global variable. I haven't tried the technique I describe above, but my guess is that the calculation for the hidden attribute isn't going to update constantly. It will probably only update when the layout gets redrawn, such as moving to a different record.

Now, having said that, there are better ways to get a script to execute periodically.

- FileMaker Server can execute a script on a schedule. I actually use this feature myself to import data from text files that contain data that was downloaded from PostgreSQL.
- FileMaker 10+ has a script step called [`Install OnTimer Script`](http://www.filemaker.com/help/14/fmp/en/html/scripts_ref1.35.18.html#1044171) which will execute a script after a specified number of seconds.

This type of script is best placed on the server, but that may not be possible because of the Actual adapter. If that's the case, then I would suggest investigating the `Install OnTimer Script` step.

Comment: We tried importing on a schedule, however we ran into random issues with ODBC import, the script runs from Filemaker Pro but failed to run as a schedule.

Comment: I have had situations where I needed to do something periodically but it couldn't be done with FileMaker Server. In such cases I kept a copy of FileMaker Pro on the same machine as the server and used `Install OnTimer Script` to execute it periodically. I would suggest trying that, which would mean that you *could* have the script clean up a global variable (and refresh the screen). However, if you want to know if the script is running while using a *different* FileMaker client, you'll need more advanced techniques, since global variables are client specific.

Comment: So, If I understand correctly, the "Install OnTimer Script" I need to run it manually, from the client, once? Then it just picks up the schedule.

Comment: The `Install OnTimer Script` script step takes as one of it's parameters the script to execute. So you'd have it as nearly the last step of whatever script you want to execute on a regular basis. To get it to run the first time, you'd execute the script with a `Perform Script` script step at launch (using the `OnFirstWindowOpen ` trigger. You'll probably also need some logic so that the `Perform Script` step only executes on one machine.